# How to prevent QtCreator from managing Git

Tags: windows, git, qt-creator

Each time I create a new file in QtCreator, it asks me if I want to add it to the Git repository, each time I delete one, it asks me if I want to remove it. I don't need QtCreator to do all that since I manage Git myself with TortoiseGit. Moreover, QtCreator is less convenient than TortoiseGit for that.

So is there any way to prevent QtCreator from managing my Git repository?

Comment: Is git support provided within a plugin?

Comment: Hmm, it should be (although it is provided with the base install). Look for ScmGit in "About plugins...", you should be able to disable it there, too. Which might actually solve your problem. That is with QtCreator 2.1, dunno how 1.x handles it.

Comment: Oh that's right, I didn't know about this "About plugins" message box. I've now disabled it. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I can tag your answer as accepted if you want (if you add it as an answer to this question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Git plugin can be disabled in "About plugins...".